# Buttonbar won't stick to bottom of screen

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to put the buttonbar I've created on the bottom of each screen. I've succeeded for the first screen fairly easy.

Now I've tried to put it other screens, but it seems that it can't stick to the bottom of the screen. When I look in the hiearchyviewer, it looks like the RelativeLayout that's wrapped araound my layout and buttonbar, isn't filling the whole screen, though, its height is set to fill parent.

Can anyone help me by pointing out where I'm going wrong?

This is the XML I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5pt" android:id="@+id/table"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:text="@string/Arbeiderbediende"
                android:id="@+id/txtArbeiderBediende" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="center">
            <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/group1">

                <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rbArbeider"
                    android:text="@string/Arbeider" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="18pt" />

                <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rbBediende"
                    android:text="@string/Bediende" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20pt" android:paddingLeft="18pt" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
            <TextView android:text="@string/OverzichtFuncties"
                android:id="@+id/txtFuncties" android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="Spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/cmbFuncties" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
            <TextView android:text="@string/Regio" android:id="@+id/txtRegio"
                android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2" android:id="@+id/cmbRegio" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
            <TextView android:text="@string/Opleiding" android:id="@+id/txtOpleidingsniveau"
                android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/cmbOpleidingsniveau" />
        </TableRow>

        <Button android:text="@string/VindJobButton" android:id="@+id/btnFindJob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />


    </TableLayout>

    <stage.accent.Toolbar android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result I achieved and the result I want to get

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you want your buttonbar to be always visible at the bottom of the screen and not scroll with the content, you might want to switch your `RelativeLayout` and `ScrollView` tags, and move your buttonbar to be the first child of your `RelativeLayout`, the `ScrollView` to be the second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <stage.accent.Toolbar android:id="id/buttonBar" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <ScrollView android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5pt" android:id="@+id/table"
            android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:text="@string/Arbeiderbediende"
                    android:id="@+id/txtArbeiderBediende" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:gravity="center">
                <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/group1">

                    <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rbArbeider"
                        android:text="@string/Arbeider" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="18pt" />

                    <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rbBediende"
                        android:text="@string/Bediende" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20pt" android:paddingLeft="18pt" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
                <TextView android:text="@string/OverzichtFuncties"
                    android:id="@+id/txtFuncties" android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="Spinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:id="@+id/cmbFuncties" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
                <TextView android:text="@string/Regio" android:id="@+id/txtRegio"
                    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2" android:id="@+id/cmbRegio" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
                <TextView android:text="@string/Opleiding" android:id="@+id/txtOpleidingsniveau"
                    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:id="@+id/cmbOpleidingsniveau" />
            </TableRow>
            <Button android:text="@string/VindJobButton" android:id="@+id/btnFindJob"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way you'll be able to achieve what you want:

[image: portrait] and [image: landscape]

The button bar will be always at the bottom of your screen.

And by scrolling the content, you'll be able to see the last bit of it too, it won't be hidden behind the buttonbar:

[image: landscape 2]

Comment: I have a question, though. What if my content is bigger than the screen. I've implemented the `ScrollView`, so scrolling won't be a problem. But the last bit of the screen, for example a submit button, will be hidden after the bar. How do you solve that?

Comment: the sample above makes the buttonbar always to be visible (it won't scroll with the content). Or am i misunderstanding you, and the submit button is not in the buttonbar?

Comment: Yes, I want the button bar to be fixed like you showed above and then there's a button, for example, that's at the bottom of the content screen. Then it's hidden behind the buttonbar.

Comment: no, it is not hidden! the scroll view ends where the buttonbar starts (`android:layout_above="@id/buttonBar"`), and you can scroll to it.
See my update (last screenshot).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing that line!

Answer (score 2):

I still suggests dont use ScrollView here is an example how you can show the ButtonBar at the bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerlayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >

        <Button android:id="@+id/amap_back_btn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="Back">
        </Button>
        <TextView  android:id="@+id/amap_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        </TextView>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/amap_action_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_menu_action"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>

    //What ever widgets you wants to add

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/map_refresh_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_refresh" 
            android:gravity="center"
            >
        </ImageButton>
        <Button android:id="@+id/map_log_btn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Log"
            android:gravity="center">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/map_map_btn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Map"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

that is all this is the most robust solution.

If you find it useful dont forget to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use ScrollViews? If my content is bigger (and on some screens it is, Android doesn't make it scroll on its own.

Comment: you can add a ListView in place of comment or scrollview in that

Answer (score 0):

> Please take one main linear layout
>   above scroll view and after ending
>   scroll view please set your bottom
>   bar..

It would be also my suggetion.
LinearLayout is the main view.
Within it

- Another LinearLayout (layout_height=0dp and layout_weight = 1) ***ll_container***
- and you tabbar

Within ***ll_container*** place

- a scrollview (layout_height=0dp and layout_weight = 1) with tablelayout
- and the button

Probably for explanation. With layout_height=0dp and layout_weight = 1 you give your layouts the whole free place remaining after placing your tabbar and then after placing your button

**UPD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5pt" android:id="@+id/table"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="@string/Arbeiderbediende"
                        android:id="@+id/txtArbeiderBediende" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:gravity="center">
                    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/group1">

                        <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rbArbeider"
                            android:text="@string/Arbeider" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="18pt" />

                        <RadioButton style="@style/RadioButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rbBediende"
                            android:text="@string/Bediende" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20pt" android:paddingLeft="18pt" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
                    <TextView android:text="@string/OverzichtFuncties"
                        android:id="@+id/txtFuncties" android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="Spinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:id="@+id/cmbFuncties" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
                    <TextView android:text="@string/Regio" android:id="@+id/txtRegio"
                        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2" android:id="@+id/cmbRegio" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="5dip">
                    <TextView android:text="@string/Opleiding" android:id="@+id/txtOpleidingsniveau"
                        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:id="@+id/cmbOpleidingsniveau" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <Button android:text="@string/VindJobButton" android:id="@+id/btnFindJob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <stage.accent.Toolbar android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With the instructions of @Chirag I've managed to do it with a relative layout and without the weights. Does it make any difference? I'd like to do it the right way.

Comment: I think, you can use both solutions. And i read your question again. And i understood that you wanted only buttonbar should be always visible. And i don't like really relative layouts ... i just had too much problems with them